# Is not a valid directory path

Tags: node.js, email-templates, swig-template

I am starting using [node-email-templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates) to send email with `swig` template and I am getting this error.

> templates/welcome.html is not a valid directory path

Here is my codes from `controllers/email.js` file.

```
var path = require('path');
var emailTemplates = require('email-templates');
var templatesDir = path.join(__dirname, '../templates');

exports.send = function(req, res) {

    emailTemplates(templatesDir, function(err, template) {

        if(err)
            console.log(err);

        var locals = {
            username: 'khayusaki@gmail.com'
        };

        template('welcome.html', locals, function(err, html, text) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
     // Send Email here!
    });
};
```

Note: The **templates** folder is in the same directory with controllers folder and which is why I use as `'../templates'`For **path.join**.

Comment: If that is same directory, ./template is enough, isn't it?

Comment: **templates** folder is the same directory with **controller** folder which is this `js` file includes.

Comment: For clarity, could you show me your directory structure?

Comment: Ah, it is working now. I just read the documentation carelessly. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: If your problem is solved, please add your fix to this problem as an answer to this question and mark it as accepted. This will help people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I carelessly read the documentation by creating `welcome.html` and just `welcome` instead of **welcome** folder. And it should be `html.{{ ext }}` inside `templates/welcome` folder.
(In my case i am using swig as `html.swig`).